# Minecraft Server RCON

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

The Minecraft server setting (RCON) I know is security. However when I tried to use RCON, it either times my friends out or lets them in without RCON. How do I fix this?

[image: ( when I'm disconnected by RCON )]

[image: when I can't connect at all]

Comment: PLease help, i just want to play a game man.

Answer (score 1):

RCON is not "security". It's a way of remote controlling your minecraft server. I use https://bukkit.org/threads/admin-rcon-mcrcon-remote-connection-client-for-minecraft-servers.70910/